# Algebraic set is irreducible $\iff$ its algebra has no zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $K$ be algebraically closed and $X\subset K^n$ be an algebraic set. I'm trying to prove $X$ is irreducible, aka $X\neq X_1\cup X_2$ for $X_1,X_2\subsetneq X$ if and only if the Algebra $K[X]=K[x_1,\dots,x_2]/I(X)$ has no zero divisors. $I$ is the vanishing ideal of $X$.

What I did was, suppose that $X$ is reducible and write it as $X=X_1\cup X_2$ then pick polynomials $f,g$ with $f$ vanishes on $X_1$ but not $X_2$ $g$ vanishes on $X_2$ and not $X$ with the product $fg$ vanishing on $X$. But this only gives me that $I(X)$ is prime. Since $K[x_1,\dots,x_2]$ is a commutative ring and for commutative rings and an ideal $I$
$$R/I \quad \text{has no zero divisors} \iff I \quad \text{prime}$$
and per contrapositve this proves the first implication.

**Is there another way of proving this without using prime ideals?**

Comment: Why shouldn't you use prime ideals? It is their very definition that makes it possible to prove it. You might call it another way, but underneath you are still using this property.

Comment: Well, yes: the cosets $fI(X)$ and $gI(X)$ are zero divisors in $K[X]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by **57Jimmy**, we already have zero divisors
$$[f+I(X)]\cdot [g+I(X)]=fg+I(X)=I(X)$$
since $fg$  vanishes on $X$. So $K[X]$ is not an integral domain.
**I didn't want to leave the question unanswered**